# Import SASS files by reference

Tags: sass

LESS CSS has got the feature where one can include a [LESS file by reference](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference).  Is this or something similar possible via SASS through the `@import` directive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass importing without compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188436/sass-importing-without-compiling)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sass partial importing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122316/sass-partial-importing)